# How to printout all the system variables , for example java.class.path

Tags: java

I am wondeirng how to print out all the system variables. I would like to know if I can enumerate them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean like?

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

or

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : System.getProperties().entrySet()) 
    System.out.println(entry);
```

Comment: when I use System.getProperties().list(System.out) why some item are displayed as *****...?

Comment: also, have a warning here Map.Entry entry Map.Entry is a raw type

Comment: list() truncates long values, which is why printing the entries yourself might be advisable.

Comment: I have changed the code so it doesn't produce a warning. Its a bit meaningless given the keys and values are all String not Object. ;)

Answer (score 3):

`System.getProperties()` is what you're after - you can then enumerate through those. You can call the `values()` or `propertyNames()` methods on the returned property object depending on whether it's the names or the values that you're after (or of course the `entrySet()` for both.)

Alternatively you can use the `list()` method directly if all you want to do is print them out somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 places where you can find a kind of system or environment variables.

1. System.getProperties()
2. System.getenv()
3. various properties of RuntimeMBean that can be accessible using `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlTool to list all or a specified Java system property on the command line.  No Java SDK or coding required.

Download the SqlTool jar file by clicking on the Download "jar" link [on this Maven repository page](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.hsqldb%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sqltool%22).

You can then dump all Java system properties with:

```
java -jar path/to/sqltool-VERSION.jar --sql "*listsysprops"
```

To list a specific system property value, just add it after 'listsysprops', like

```
java -jar path/to/sqltool-VERSION.jar --sql "*listsysprops user.home"
```