# How do I find details about the OpenJDK Provider from Command Line

Tags: java, bash

There are many providers of OpenJDK, Namely Amazon – Corretto, Azul, IBM, Oracle, RedHat etc.

OpenJDK came per-installed with my OS. So, I have no idea regarding my OpenJDK provider.

When I Query for the version it shows -

```
blueray@blueray-i58600K:~$ java --version
openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

**How can I confirm the identity of my OpenJDK provider?**

Comment: Have you tried `apt-cache showpkg openjdk` and see what that shows?

Comment: After you suggested, I tried `apt-cache showpkg openjdk-11-jdk`. It shows nothing about the provider.

Comment: The only way seems to be to search in google for the build version string.

Comment: What is build version string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `jshell` at the command-line.

Copy-Paste the Following Lines in the REPL -

```
System.out.println("java Vendor URL : "+System.getProperty("java.vendor.url"));
System.out.println("java Vendor : "+System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
System.out.println("java Version : "+System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println("Java Runtime Name : "+System.getProperty("java.runtime.name"));
System.out.println("Java Runtime Version : "+System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
System.out.println("Java Runtime Version : "+Runtime.version());
System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine Specification Name : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.name"));
System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine Specification Version  : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version")); 
System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine Specification Vendor : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.vendor"));
System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine Implementation Name : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine Implementation Version : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine Implementation Vendor : "+System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor"));
```

Press **Enter**

### **References**

[Which JRE I am using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472121/which-jre-i-am-using)

[How to know if I am using Open JDK or Oracle JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895107/how-to-know-if-i-am-using-open-jdk-or-oracle-jdk)

[How to printout all the system variables , for example java.class.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242678/how-to-printout-all-the-system-variables-for-example-java-class-path/8242703)

[How to find the JVM version from a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103121/how-to-find-the-jvm-version-from-a-program/37117187#37117187)

[Essential Classes > The Platform Environment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

**Apology and Disclaimer:** I apologize because I am sure I missed some references.

Comment: You can also use /edit, then copy all of the system.out lines to the editor, then press Accept for a cleaner display.